# Ajax call works properly but php file get error when retrieving attributes from object

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

This must be a simple syntax error but i can't get. So in my HTML i have some empty tags (tbody)

```
    <label for="matiere2">Classe :</label>
                <select name="matiere2" id="matiere1" onchange="showList(this.value)">
                    <option></option>
                    '.$this->addClasseToselect().'
                </select>
            <div class="tableau">
            <table>
                <caption>Mes listes</caption>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Quantité</th>
                        <th>Libellé</th>
                        <th>Supprimer</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tbody">
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

I also have select with onchange ajax function to get right data in the table
here is my js file with only one ajax function

```
    function showList(str) {
       if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("tbody").innerHTML = "";
        return;
      } else {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        var versions = ["MSXML2.XmlHttp.5.0",
            "MSXML2.XmlHttp.4.0",
            "MSXML2.XmlHttp.3.0",
            "MSXML2.XmlHttp.2.0",
            "Microsoft.XmlHttp"]

        for(var i = 0, len = versions.length; i < len; i++) {
            try {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject(versions[i]);
                break;
            }
            catch(e){}
        } // end for
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("tbody").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","vue/getliste.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

}
The php file (getliste.php) called in the function :

```
    <?php
    include_once ('../modele/liste.php');
    $q = intval($_GET['q']);
    $res='';
    foreach($listes=liste::findAllByIdAndClasse($q) as $c){
    var_dump($c);
    $res.='<tr><td>'.$c->__get['quantite'].'</td><td>'.$c->__get['intitule'].'</td><td><a class="del_button" type="button" onclick="document.getElementById(\'light\').style.display=\'block\';document.getElementById(\'fade\').style.display=\'block\'" id="">X</a></td></tr>';
    }
    echo $res;
```

Here is what i get from the var_dump(), so my data is properly loaded:

```
    object(liste)[3]
    private 'id' => string '23' (length=2)
    private 'quantite' => string '7' (length=1)
    private 'intitule' => string 'Mcdo' (length=4)
    private 'idClasse' => string '18' (length=2)
    private 'idMatiere' => string '11' (length=2)
    private 'idProf' => string '53' (length=2).
```

Here is my class 'liste' with its attributes, the __get method and the method findAllByIdAndClasse(id) used in getliste.php
        class liste {

```
private $id;
private $quantite;
private $intitule;
private $idClasse;
private $idMatiere;
private $idProf;

function __construct()
{
}


public function __get($attr_name) {
    if (property_exists( __CLASS__, $attr_name)) {
        return $this->$attr_name;
    }
    $emess=__CLASS__ . ": unknown member $attr_name (getAttr)";
    throw new Exception($emess, 45);
}
```

and findAllByIdAndName(id) , still in liste.php

```
    public static function findAllByIdAndClasse($q){
    session_start();
    $c=base::getConnection();
    $query=$c->prepare("select * from liste WHERE idProf=:idProf AND idClasse=:idClasse ORDER BY idClasse ASC ");
    $query->bindParam(':idProf',$_SESSION['userid'],PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindParam(':idClasse',$q,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $dbres=$query->execute();
    $d=$query->fetchAll();
    $tab=array();
    foreach ($d as $key => $value) {
        $a=new liste();
        $a->id=$value['id'];
        $a->quantite=$value['quantite'];
        $a->intitule=$value['intitule'];
        $a->idClasse=$value['idClasse'];
        $a->idProf=$value['idProf'];
        $a->idMatiere=$value['idMatiere'];
        $tab[]=$a;


    }
    return $tab;
}
```

I get a php error stating that i'm trying to get an attribute that doesn't exist, i check the spelling of it and it seem right, my only clue is that it's a syntax error with some ' " problems but i can' get it... Any help appreciated, thx!

EDIT

So now i have tried adding a var_dump in my __get function just before the if, so it becomes :

```
    public function __get($attr_name) {
var_dump($attr_name);
if (property_exists( __CLASS__, $attr_name)) {
    return $this->$attr_name;
}
$emess=__CLASS__ . ": unknown member $attr_name (getAttr)";
throw new Exception($emess, 45);
```

}
And the result i get from it is :

```
string '__get' (length=5)
```

So it means this line :

```
$res.='<tr><td>'.$c->__get['quantite'].'</td><td>'.$c->__get['intitule'].'</td></tr>';
```

Is sending $c->__get[__get]....hmm I don't get it...

Comment: at what line is the php-error?

Comment: Error comes from php file just after the var_dump, where i create my string to be inserted in the tbody

Comment: I don't know what your liste-class-method does with $q, but shouldn't it just be `$c->quantite` instead of `$c->__get['quantite']`?

Comment: The properties are private. Better show your model, in particular the __get method if you are overriding it

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: But since my var_dump returns the good value, i don't think it's a problem in my model..

Comment: It is very strange to set private properties and then let the __get method return properties with any access. Why not just use public properties in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your last line of code:

```
$res.='<tr><td>'.$c->__get['quantite'].'</td><td>'.$c->__get['intitule'].'</td></tr>';
```

It should read...

```
$res.='<tr><td>'.$c->quantite.'</td><td>'.$c->intitule.'</td></tr>';
```

The "__get" function catches undefined properties using "magic". In your code the undefined property you are trying to read is "__get" which is what you var_dump is showing.

Look at the PHP manual for more details...
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

Comment: Yeah i also found this solution ! Thx. I think i was also making the mistake of calling it with __get[''] instead of __get('')....